# Ansible resetting swap linux

Tags: ansible, linux

I am newbie to Ansible, i failed using ansible via command that way :

```
ansible host -a "/sbin/swapoff -a && /sbin/swapon -a"
```

Only this worked

```
ansible host -a "/sbin/swapoff -a
ansible host -a "/sbin/swapon -a
```

I am thinking of making a playbook, starting maybe with this:

```
- name: Turn off swap
  shell : "swapoff -a"

- name: Turn on swap
  shell : "swapon -a"
```

I would like to **reset swap space** with a condition, only when the swap used space is **greater** than **100mb**. Is it possible to do that ?

Many thanks for your help

Comment: While I agree that there are cases where you want to clear swap space, do read https://askubuntu.com/a/1379/561783 to make sure you are not spending too much time on a non-issue :)

Comment: and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/220065/is-clearing-a-full-swap-necessary-wise

Comment: Thanks for the links :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly do this through a handler or task, but first you need to generate the trigger conditions. The swap space is in the [Ansible facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#facts) that are returned when `setup:` is run. From the Ansible docs:

> Facts
>
> These are variables that contain information pertinent to the current host (inventory_hostname). They are only available if gathered first.
>
> ansible_facts
>      Contains any facts gathered or cached for the inventory_hostname Facts are normally gathered by the setup module automatically in a play, but any module can return facts.
>
> ansible_local
>      Contains any ‘local facts’ gathered or cached for the inventory_hostname. The keys available depend on the custom facts created. See the setup module for more details.

As an example:

```
ansible -i localhost, all -c local -m setup -a filter=*swap*
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "ansible_swapfree_mb": 437,
        "ansible_swaptotal_mb": 979
    },
    "changed": false
}
```

In your playbook your task to reset swap should then have the conditional like:

`when: ansible_swap_free_mb < 500`

In your case, however you want to trigger on swap used, so you would have to compute the difference between total and free.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, i need to check how i can use handler or task. It's very new for me. About one simple playbook i try that :

```
- hosts: host-test-bdd1
  tasks:
    - name: We desactivate swap
      command: swapoff -a
      when: ansible_swap_free_mb < 1600

    - name: We active swap
      command: swapon -a
```
But i still don't know where to put the condition "when" exactly

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution on that way :

```
---
- hosts: hostnametest
  tasks:
   - name: we take swap space used (megabytes)
     shell : free -m | grep Swap | awk '{print $3}'
     register: swap_used

   - name: Turn off swap
     shell: "swapoff -a"
     when: (swap_used.stdout_lines[0] | int) > 100

   - name: Turn on swap
     shell: "swapon -a"
     when: (swap_used.stdout_lines[0] | int) > 100
```

Comment: Your first task should only be marked as changed when the threshold you want is exceeded. So move the "when" clause to a "changed_when" for the first task.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, really perfect, i just did the "when" to "changed_when" for the first task, it works well ! Nice to learn this "changed_when" :)